# What is "expletive you" in grammer?

Tags: grammar, offensive-language

I always interpret "expletive you" as an imperative statement with an implicit subject of "I", although the (less than intelligent) speaker clearly doesn't think of it in this light.

Is there any basis for considering it otherwise?

P.S. - It seems to me that it would be so much easier for the submitter to type relevant tags in rather than this bizarre system - that I'm still struggling to decipher.

Comment: Comments on the usability of the site should be made on [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Although possible, it's rare for imperatives to be in anything other than the second person. Also, I can't really imagine the *meaning* of an expletive to be *Let me [do something] to you.* Despite the actual syntax, it's almost always interpretable as *You [do something]!* or *You [do something] to yourself!*

Comment: As I suggested, no doubt the person saying it has no idea that it can mean "I do something to you"  Where does "let me" come from?  This is based on the notion that sentences lacking a subject are automatically assigned an implicit one - the speaker in this case.

Comment: It may be interpretable in those ways, but only by someone lacking intelligence.

Comment: I think the question could be clearer. The title is fine (it needs to be Safe For Work) but there is actually no need to shy away from actually quoting the offensive language in order to ask about it. It would also help if you could explain "imperative with an implicit subject of *I*" because that's not how imperatives work.

Comment: When I say "Damn you!" to someone I am not suggesting that I can, or want to, damn them myself, and I don't think that I am suggesting that they should damn themselves either. I think I am saying "May you be damned [e.g. by God]". Likewise "Fuck you!" expresses the wish that they shall be either painfully penetrated or figuratively "fucked" (ruined). My father used to say "Bugger him!" about men he despised, and I think the foregoing remarks apply to that.

Comment: I believe "expletive" to be a meta-swear word. The use would be "F*** you." or any variation and have the same imperative status as the comments suggest. The use of "expletive" became commonplace with transcriptions of Nixon's Watergate tapes. This would be the same as "'f' you." with the 'f' standing for you/they know what.